# newbie json question

Tags: json

I have 2 files.

1: json.php;

```
<?php

$data = array(
(object)array(
    'oV' => 'myfirstvalue',
    'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
),
(object)array(
    'oV' => 'mysecondvalue',
    'oT' => 'mysecondtext',
),
);

$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
?>
```

1. test.html:

   ```
   $(function () { 
   $.ajax({
   url: "json.php",
   dataType: "json", 
   success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
   });

   });
   ```

But i dont see my data object in the console. What did i miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($data);
```

This tells the browser what its retrieving.

Comment: I have added "header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: '.date('r',time()-86400));
header('Content-type: application/json');" without success...

Comment: When you echo the encoded json with PHP you're simply outputting serialized text, not a JSON object. jQuery then turns the serialized string back into a traversible JSON object upon retrieval. Try using Chuck's suggestion and see if it helps.

You might also try simply alerting the data to see if it's actually coming through.

Comment: @BraedenP, i did not get any other results when adding his code. I have already added a console.log to see if i get my json object. Thanks though

Comment: I tried your exact code, and when alerting the data, I got two JSON objects, just like I was supposed to get.

Comment: Wierd, if i change console.log(data); to alert(data); i dont get any alert. Im using my code posted above + header("Content-type: text/plain");

Comment: When i made my .html file a .php, it seems to be working. Doesnt html files work for this type of stuff?

Comment: Yeah, they do. That's definitely odd behavior.